# How to insert data to jTable from jTextFields?

Tags: java, swing

I can't insert the data values from jTextFields to jTables.

My addCustomerToTable is a function with a parameter that comes from another class. What did i do wrong?

I check the variables they have the values from other class but i can't insert them to the jTable rows.

```
public void addCustomerToTable(int accountNum, String fname, String mname, String lname, double deposit){
    String account = Integer.toString(accountNum);
    String fnames = fname;
    String mnames = mname;
    String lnames = lname;
    String deposits = Double.toString(deposit);

    //table.setRowCount(table.getRowCount()+1);
    //DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel table = new DefaultTableModel();        
    jTable2.setModel(table);
    Object row[] = {account, fnames, mnames, lnames, deposits};
    table.addRow(row);  
}
```

Comment: You have two choices, either use `setValueAt` for updating existing rows or `addRow` to add a new row to an existing model.  What you don't want to do, is create a new `TableModel` and do nothing with, like you have...

Comment: so how will i get  what i want with what you have said?

Comment: To me, this `DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();` seemed like a good start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you basically had the solution...

```
public void addCustomerToTable(int accountNum, String fname, String mname, String lname, double deposit){
    String account = Integer.toString(accountNum);
    String fnames = fname;
    String mnames = mname;
    String lnames = lname;
    String deposits = Double.toString(deposit);

    DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    Object row[] = {account, fnames, mnames, lnames, deposits};
    table.addRow(row);  
}
```

You get the `DefaultTableModel` from the `JTable` and you use it's `addRow` functionality.

If this isn't working then there is something else wrong with your code which you're not showing use and you should consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

You may also wish to take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: i tried this but when i tried to run the code my table got missing

Comment: So, you have a problem else where in your code. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Yes I think the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a new `TableModel`, just get the `jTable` current `TableModel` and add row to it directly:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[] {account, fnames, mnames, lnames, deposits});
```

Take a look at [**Appending a Row to a JTable Component**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AppendingaRowtoaJTableComponent.htm) for further information.

**EDIT:**

If the problem is still happening then you may have another issue in your code, check wether you have the same number of columns in the `jTable`, it maybe that this new Row can't be added to the Model.